# Cannot connect through TCP/IP protocol

Tags: windows, networking, google-chrome, dns

The title is my inspection on the issue, it may not be the real issue.

The issue is, my browsers cannot connect to any domains, such as google.com.

Under IE 11, there is no error but just a plain "Cannot connect to Internet".
Under Chrome, the error name is "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN".

And if I "ping google.com", I get:

Ping request cannot found hostname google.com. Please check the name and retry. (I am not using English version of Windows so that's my rough translations)

BUT, if I use "nslookup google.com", I get:

Server: google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address: 8.8.8.8

(Yes, I am using Google's DNS for years)

Name: google.com
Addresses: 2404:6800:4005:80b::200e
           118.143.88.103
           ....and a series of IPv4 addresses

Now, if I try to open 118.143.88.103,

under IE, it works fine.
under Chrome, it works fine.

So my problem is that, my browsers cannot resolve a domain but directly using the IP works perfectly.

I am using Windows 8.1. Using other software that is not using the TCP/IP port, such as Skype or TeamSpeak, they work fine. But if the software contains some elements that are actually webpages, such as Spotify's homepage, they fail.

I have tried numerous solutions on the Internet. Such as:

- Changing DNS to automatic or manually
- Different DNS servers such as OpenDNS or Google DNS
- netsh int ip reset, netsh int ipv4 reset, netsh int ipv6 reset, netsh winsock reset catalog
- Deleting Winsock and Winsock2 directories in registry
- Rebooting router and computer
- Reinstalling TCP/IP drivers

Other devices can connect to the router and able to browse the web.

EDIT: Strangely, Firefox works!

Comment: *"I am using Windows 8.1"*. 'Nuff said.

Comment: @EugenRieck Well, apologies to that.

Comment: System Restore to a date/time when it was working?

Comment: @DavidPostill I am afraid that I never created any system restore point :(

Comment: Did it previously work?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes. It stopped working some days ago. The issue was like suddenly appears.

Comment: Maybe a broken windows update? Normally Windows update creates restore points for you... "AutoUpdate installation. AutoUpdate provides an easy way for users to download critical Windows updates. After the update is downloaded, the user can install the update on the system. If the user chooses to install the update, System Restore creates a restore point before the installation of the update begins."